# How can I rewrite this set?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**The Problem**

I need to prove that the set

> $\{-(0^2+1) \bmod p, -(1^2+1) \bmod p, -(2^2+1) \bmod p, \dotsc,
>  -(((p-1)/2)^2+1) \bmod p\}$

has $(p+1)/2$ elements, where $p$ is an odd prime.

---

**My Question**

I think to prove this I first need to use the fact that

> $x^2\equiv (-x)^2 \pmod p$

and/or

> $x^2\equiv (p-x)^2 \pmod p$

to rewrite the set into something I can work with.  I'm having trouble doing this since for some reason.  Am I missing something?

---

**Additional Information**

I proved in the previous problem that the set

> $\{0^2 \bmod p, 1^2 \bmod p, \dotsc, ((p-1)/2)^2 \bmod p\}$

also has $(p+1)/2$ elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears what you have to prove is that if $0\le j<k\le\frac12(p-1)$ then
$$-(j^2+1)\not\equiv-(k^2+1)\pmod p.$$
This conclusion is the same as
$$j^2+1\not\equiv k^2+1\pmod p,$$
which is the same as
$$j^2-k^2\not\equiv 0\pmod p.\tag1$$
So, all you have to do is prove your conditions on $j$ and $k$ imply $(1)$;
you will need to use the fact that $p$ is prime (did you mention that?).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I added that detail in!  Thanks for the quick response!